# Trying to obtain gray images from webcam using Visual Basic, OpenCV and EmguCV

Tags: vb.net, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am learning about OpenCV and EmguCV. I succeed by trying to obtain images from my webcam and now I'm trying to obtain that images in a gray scale.

My purpose after achieve this, is to recognize and track colors, so im trying to obtain the image in a HVS format to filter the image to display only the color Im looking for in white, and the rest of the image in black (I hope you understand my explanation)

Now, I only want to obtain the image from my webcam in that gray scale using the following code:

```
Imports Emgu.CV

Imports Emgu.CV.Util

Imports Emgu.CV.Structure

Imports System.Drawing

Public Class Form1

Dim capturez As Capture = New Capture
Dim radius As Decimal = 50.0F
Dim x As Decimal
Dim y As Decimal

Private Sub Timer1_Tick() Handles Timer1.Tick

    'Define x and y to determinate the position of the circle in the PictureBox
    x = PictureBox1.Width / 2 - radius
    y = PictureBox1.Height / 2 - radius

    'PointF type defines the X and Y position of the future circle in the PictureBox
    Dim point1 As New PointF(x, y)
    Dim circle As CircleF = New CircleF(point1, radius)
    Dim img As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = capturez.QueryFrame()

    'Convert camera capture from BGR to HVS
    Dim hvs_frame As Image(Of Hsv, Byte) = img.Convert(Of Hsv, Byte)()

    'Obtain the three channels that compose the HVS image (hue, saturation and value)
    Dim channels As Image(Of Gray, Byte)() = hvs_frame.Split()


    'Remove all pixels from the hue channel that are not in the range [40, 60]
    CvInvoke.cvInRangeS(channels(0), New Gray(200).MCvScalar, New Gray(255).MCvScalar, channels(0))

    'Display converted frame
    PictureBox1.Image = channels(0).ToBitmap()

    'When commenting the .CopyBlank() property, the back color of the PictureBox remains transparent
    'When uncomment this, the back color of the PictureBox becomes black
    Dim imageCircle As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = img '.CopyBlank()
    imageCircle.Draw(circle, New Bgr(Color.Brown), 2)
    PictureBox1.Image = imageCircle.ToBitmap()
End Sub
```

With this code, I am only obtaining the image in BGR, and I don't know why, because I am specifying in the 'PictureBox1.Image' that I want the image in that gray scale.

Please help me =(

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 and EmguCV 2.4.0 ... if needed

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Accepting an answer marks the question as "solved". You don't need to pop it into the title. Keep that as clean as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are capturing the image in color (`BGR`) so you can't just show one channel in your `Picturebox` as this won't be a `GrayScale` image (it's the `Blue` channel, since it's a `BGR` image). You can solve this in two ways.

The first option is to specifically retrieve the frame from your camera in `GrayScale`. You can achieve this like this:

```
Dim imgGrayscale As Image(Of Gray, Byte) = capturez.RetrieveGrayFrame()
```

The other option is to convert your image to `GrayScale` after you've retrieved it from the webcam capture. You can achieve this like this:

```
Dim img As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = capturez.QueryFrame()
Dim imgGrayscale As Image(Of Gray, Byte) = img.Convert(Of Gray, Byte)()
```

Note that from this moment you will be working with a `GrayScale` image, which will impact the rest of your code (i.e. you will not have 3 channels anymore, etc.). Therefore the second option may be more suitable for you, as you will now have a `Bgr` and a `GrayScale`. You can now still use the `Bgr` image for your `HSV` conversion etc.

You can now show the `GrayScale` image like this:

```
PictureBox1.Image = imgGrayscale.ToBitmap()
```

**EDIT to threshold one color, instead of converting to grayscale:**

If you want to extract one color from the image, you *can't use* `Grayscale`, even though the result will be a one channel image. This is because you need all channel values to extract the right color. Follow the following steps:

- Retrieve you `Bgr` image and convert it to `Hsv` as you did.
- *Don't* split your image into three channels, but just create a new empty image to store your color threshold result in
- Call the `CvInvoke.InRange` function, but apply the scalar to all three HSV channels. I recommend the use of `InRange` and not `InRangeS` as the latter is from OpenCV 1.X.
- The `InRange` function works as follows: the `MCvScalars` represent the bounds of your color values in `HSV` range. It checks each pixel and compares if it is within the scalar values you stated. If it is, it will get a `255` pixel value (white) and otherwise `0` (black). That will give you a thresholded image.
- If you want to extract more ranges of colors, you can add more `CvInvoke.Inrange` methods and add the different results with a `CvInvoke.Add` function later.
- Experiment with the `MCvScalar` bounds you set to extract your color if they don't give you the right result. Also, if you want to obtain a different color, modify the bounds. You can use color pickers to retrieve the `HSV` values of certain color. Even a color picker in MS Paint will give you the `Hue/Sat/Lum` values, but you have to convert these (they are on a different scale, `MS Paint 0-239` and `OpenCV 0-179`). So convert them by multiplying the levels by `180/240`.

You will get something like this:

```
` Get the webcam frame
Dim webcam_image As Mat
webcam_image = capturez.QueryFrame()

` Get an empty HSV image and threshold image
Dim HSV_img As New Mat(webcam_image.Size, DepthType.Cv8U, 3)
Dim threshold_img As New Mat(webcam_image.Size, DepthType.Cv8U, 1)

' Convert camera capture from BGR to HVS
CvInvoke.CvtColor(webcam_image, HSV_img, ColorConversion.Bgr2Hsv)

` Threshold the yellow colors only (please adopt the scalar values to whatever values suit your needs)
CvInvoke.InRange(HSV_img, New ScalarArray(New MCvScalar(20, 100, 100)), New ScalarArray(New MCvScalar(30, 255, 255)), threshold_img)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot NuclearPenguin! Now I have my image in a gray scale!! Let me ask you one more thing please. What if I want to obtain only one colour, like, for example, white, or yellow. I mean, that colour that I want to obtain, convert to white, and the rest of the colours convert to black. I have to do it from that grayscale image or I have to do it from the bgr image? Example: I want to take a picture from the sun, but I want to see only the sun in white, and the rest of the colours in black. I hope you can help me!

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to extract one color and threshold it, you have to take different steps (you were already on the right track). It's quite long, so I added it to my original answer. I hope that covers all questions for you! Also, if this answer solved your problem don't forget to accept it as answer.

Comment: Finally I extract one colour!! haha.. in this thread I've already posted with another problem, you can see how I achieve that if you want to see it. Thanks a lot! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211664/taking-one-capture-and-displaying-the-one-before-vb-opencv