# Taking one capture and displaying the one before - VB - OpenCV

Tags: vb.net, opencv, emgucv

I am having a special problem with capturing a picture using my webcam, opencv and emgucv.

I have used this function before, and always worked well, but now, I don't know why, the picturebox is showing me the picture taken before. Let me explain:

I start the program - I press the button and wait some seconds before the picture is taken - I take the picture using img = capturez.QueryFrame() - I display the picture in the PictureBox. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub startButton_Click() Handles startButton.Click

    Dim timeToWait As Integer
    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
    If globalGMT <> Nothing And globalLatitude <> Nothing And globalLongitude <> Nothing Then
        'If TextBox_GMT.Text IsNot Nothing And TextBox_LAT.Text IsNot Nothing And TextBox_LON.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        SunPosition(globalGMT, globalLatitude, globalLongitude, ELEVACIONDELSOL, AZIMUTDELSOL)
    End If
    startButton.Enabled = False
    SetDefaultTimeButton.Enabled = False
    SetParameters.Enabled = False
    TextBoxTime.Text = System.DateTime.UtcNow

    timeToWait = globalTimeLeft

    For i = 0 To timeLeft
        wait()
        i += 1
        timeToWait -= 1
        timeLabel.Text = timeToWait & " seconds"
    Next

    Dim img As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = capturez.QueryFrame()

    For x = 0 To img.Width - 1
        For y = 0 To img.Height - 1
            Dim pixelColor As Bgr = img(y, x)

            If (pixelColor.Blue >= 200 And pixelColor.Blue <= 255) And
               (pixelColor.Green >= 200 And pixelColor.Green <= 255) And (pixelColor.Red >= 200 And pixelColor.Red <= 255) Then
                pixelColor.Blue = 255
                pixelColor.Green = 255
                pixelColor.Red = 255
                img(y, x) = pixelColor
            Else
                pixelColor.Blue = 0
                pixelColor.Green = 0
                pixelColor.Red = 0
                img(y, x) = pixelColor
            End If
        Next
    Next

    PictureBox1.Image = img.ToBitmap

    startButton.Enabled = True
    SetParameters.Enabled = True
    SetDefaultTimeButton.Enabled = True
    SetForm()

End Sub
```

The function wait() looks like this:

```
Private Sub wait()
    Dim seconds As Integer = 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To seconds * 100
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
        'Application.DoEvents()
    Next
End Sub
```

Maybe you can ask, why don't you use a timer for that? It is because with the timer I am having exactly the same problem. Here is the code using the timer:

```
'This function will start the activity of the form
Private Sub startButton_Click() Handles startButton.Click

    Dim timeToWait As Integer
    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
    If globalGMT <> Nothing And globalLatitude <> Nothing And globalLongitude <> Nothing Then
        'If TextBox_GMT.Text IsNot Nothing And TextBox_LAT.Text IsNot Nothing And TextBox_LON.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        SunPosition(globalGMT, globalLatitude, globalLongitude, ELEVACIONDELSOL, AZIMUTDELSOL)
    End If
    startButton.Enabled = False
    SetDefaultTimeButton.Enabled = False
    SetParameters.Enabled = False
    TextBoxTime.Text = System.DateTime.UtcNow
    StartButtonTimer.Start()
End Sub

'This function will start the timer of the form 
Private Sub StartButtonTimer_Tick() Handles StartButtonTimer.Tick
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer

    If timeLeft > 0 Then
        timeLeft -= 1
        timeLabel.Text = timeLeft & " seconds"

        'DLE prueba tomar foto después del tiempo especificado - pongo a negro el fondo del picturebox
        PictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Black
    Else

        'DLE prueba tomar foto después del tiempo especificado - hago foto de lo que ve la camara
        Dim img As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = capturez.QueryFrame()

        For X = 0 To img.Width - 1
            For Y = 0 To img.Height - 1
                Dim pixelColor As Bgr = img(Y, X)

                If (pixelColor.Blue >= 200 And pixelColor.Blue <= 255) And
                   (pixelColor.Green >= 200 And pixelColor.Green <= 255) And
                   (pixelColor.Red >= 200 And pixelColor.Red <= 255) Then
                    pixelColor.Blue = 255
                    pixelColor.Green = 255
                    pixelColor.Red = 255
                    img(Y, X) = pixelColor
                Else
                    pixelColor.Blue = 0
                    pixelColor.Green = 0
                    pixelColor.Red = 0
                    img(Y, X) = pixelColor
                End If
            Next
        Next
        StartButtonTimer.Stop()
        PictureBox1.Image = img.ToBitmap
        startButton.Enabled = True
        SetParameters.Enabled = True
        SetDefaultTimeButton.Enabled = True
        SetForm()
    End If
End Sub
```

The function SetForm() only enables some buttons.

The problem is:
I take the first picture - The picturebox shows the first picture.
I take the second picture - The picturebox shows the first picture again.
I take the third picture - The picturebox shows the second picture.
I take the fourth picture - The picturebox shows the third picture.
...
...
After taking the picture, I'm only recognizing a colour and show that colour in white and the rest of the picture in black (if someone needs this explanation)

Thanks for any help you could give me!

EDIT: if I add this line at the end of the function: Dim image As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = capturez.QueryFrame(), it works well:

```
...
        ...
        Next
        StartButtonTimer.Stop()
        PictureBox1.Image = img.ToBitmap
        startButton.Enabled = True
        SetParameters.Enabled = True
        SetDefaultTimeButton.Enabled = True
        SetForm()
    End If

    Dim image As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = capturez.QueryFrame()

End Sub
```

End Class

I don't use this last variable for nothing, only I am declaring it without use it. I don't understand why with this line it works well, and when I erase it, it doesn´t works..

Comment: A quick search came up with lots of hits pointing to `OpenCV.QueryFrame()` as the culprit.  One [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7517099/2330053) basically suggests continuously polling `QueryFrame()` so that the most current image is always ready for you to retrieve.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I finally decide to use a new QUeryFrame at the end and works perfectly, so I think I am going to use that solution. Thanks a lot for for help and reply!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this about, but I believe the problem is that you don't `Dispose` your capture. Since you only capture one frame on a button click (and you don't have a live webcam stream) you should `Dispose` of your `Capture` object after you use it. What happens now is that you ask for a new frame, the `Capture` object will return the old frame and then starts retrieving another one that's ready for next use. Therefore, if you put another `QueryFrame()` at the end of your method it works again, since the old frame is overwritten.

This should solve your problem:

```
'Make sure you can use your retrieved image even after the dispose
Dim img As Image(Of Bgr, Byte);

'Create a new capture object
Using capturez As New Capture
    'Since it's a new object the webcam is forced to retrieve a frame now
    'Also, use Copy() to make sure your image is still available after diposing
    img = capturez.QueryFrame().Copy()
End Using 'Dispose the object now 

'Now do with your img object whatever you want!
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am trying what you say about do that using block and it works perfectly. The problem with this solution, is that the capture delays between 1-2 seconds, and I dont know why. About the other solution, i mean, to put another QueryFrame() at the end, that works perfectly and does not delay the capture, so I think I am going to use that solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good to hear! The delay is because the webcam has to be started again. That takes a little while.